# How do I fix error "Invalid locator strategy: css selector"

Tags: appium, robotframework

I'm new to robotframework, I have just installed `Python 2.7.9`, wxpython2.8.1 unicode and `ride 1.3` then appiumlibrary. When I run a test with the KeyWord `"Click Element"`:

`Click Element  id=fr.axa.soon.qa:id/subscription`

I get an error message :

> WebDriverException: Message: Invalid locator strategy: css selector

I know it's not a css selector, but I'm on a native app and I don't understand why this isn't a AppiumDriver.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Problem solved. I had `selenium 1.46.1` installed, I installed 1.46.0 and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having the same issue and luckily I caught it after just installing Selenium 2.46.1.

I immediately downgraded back down to 2.46.0 and now clicking buttons work again.

Not sure if you can use pip to downgrade, but I just downloaded version 2.46.0 here: [Download Selenium 2.46.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/2.46.0)

Go to the directory and enter into terminal:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thank's, but I have solved my problem yesterday. You can downgrade with pip : `pip install selenium == 2.46.0`